# How is DJI OcuSync wireless link physical layer implemented?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, synchronization

I'm looking for documentation on the wireless command link of the DJI OcuSync. I found this [website](https://www.zhihu.com/question/51662068) (in Chinese). It seems like an OFDM link that uses Alamouti codes?

I'm specifically interested in the receiver signal processing involved in synchronization of this link. Can anyone point me to useful papers or block diagrams?

Comment: If you have access to the device, look for its FCC ID number and look it up in the FCC's website. They are required to post certain technical docs there.

Comment: @MBaz I do happen to know a company that specializes in the decoding of such links. It's hard, DJI has custom silicon, it's not the OFDM that you are used to, it's not a standard channel code IIRC … The patents and FCC docs themselves aren't sufficient for decoding. In other words, it's an industry secret and (most?) of that companies competition is years behind.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what's the name of the company?

Comment: Sorry, not able to disclose names of clients, or customers or clients of customers or customers of clients or friends in companies or anything similar; hope you understand.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's interesting, thanks for the info.